# Solution found but account empty

Tags: ethminer

Two times ethminer logged that it found a solution, like the one in the screenshot. But my account is still empty.

I start geth with: `geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain localhost 2`

On other screens on the net, there is much more info when a solution is found, like several hash values. Why is mine just displaying the nonce?

[image]

Comment: Is this on a pool? Solo mining? I see you're pointing your miners at `127.0.0.1`, but you might be running a proxy to a pool.

Comment: I start geth with: `geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain localhost 2`

Comment: Is your `geth` done syncing the blockchain? With the hash rate you have, it would take a very long time to find a block on the Ethereum main net; if you've found two recently, that suggests to me your blockchain is not done syncing (difficulty used to be lower, so you'd find more blocks) or there is something wrong with the sync process. `geth` should indicate that the latest block is after 3949200.

Comment: Also, which screenshots are you comparing this to? Could be a different piece of miner software. Should not make a difference to whether or not your account is credited for a block.

Comment: Now my blockchain is synced. When I switch to a pool, all my mining till now was meaningless, I suppose.